# Comparing ENUMS

Tags: java, comparable

I am trying to write some code about a farm. The farm has different types of animals, described as Enums. I want to write a comparator that would compare the animals and tell which one is bigger. How could I manually tell him Cow is bigger than a dog, if these two have no parameters that could be compared to? for ex. there is no Cow.size=10, Dog.size=2, so if we compare the size we get the bigger. I just have ENUMS, and I want tell my comparator that if it compares a cow and a dog the cow is bigger. I have read online that the interface **Comparable**  is very useful for this, but I couldn`t understand, how could I implement it on my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you write a code that compares in a particular order (for example, alphabetically)? Do you know how to use the interface?

Comment: Please show us your own [mcve] code including your best attempt at a solution, and use this to hone down your question. This would make your question much more specific, much easier to answer, and much less likely to be a duplicate of the many other similar "how to use Comparable or a Comparator" type questions.

Comment: Also note that *something* has to hold the "size" field of the Animal enum since this can be a value that is pulled from thin air, if not the enum itself (the best solution) then at least an `EnumMap<Animal, Integer>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you could do, I'll give two options.

### Option 1

Use `Enum`'s [implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E)) of `Comparable` to your advantage.

> The natural order implemented by this method is the order in which the constants are declared.

This means you could declare each constant from smallest animal to largest animal. Then you'd document that `compareTo` doesn't just correspond to the declaration order but also the size of the animals represented by each constant.

### Option 2

Assign a "size" to each constant. For instance, if size was an `int`:

```
public enum Animal {
    CAT(0),
    COW(2),
    DOG(1),
    ELEPHANT(3);

    public static Comparator<Animal> getSizeComparator() {
        return Comparator.comparingInt(Animal::getSize);
    }

    private final int size;

    Animal(final int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

}
```

Then you would compare sizes of `Animal`s by using `getSize()`<sup>1</sup> (as the `Comparator` returned by `getSizeComparator()` does). If you might add more constants in the future you should document that the value returned by `getSize()` is only useful relative to other `Animal`s. In other words, the *actual* value of `getSize()` means nothing and should not be relied upon.

---

<sup>1. You cannot override the `compareTo` method of `Enum` as it is declared final.</sup>

Comment: Also give it a static method: `public static Comparator<Animal> getComparator() {
        return Comparator.comparingInt(Animal::getSize);
    }`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Added. I actually had something similar when I was writing it in my IDE (it was a static constant instead) but I thought maybe it was too much noise. But you're right, it is more complete with that method and the question _does_ mention wanting to "write a comparator".

Comment: The option 1 was the perfect solution for me. Thanks